# How to get value of "this"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To Do</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>To Do</h2>
        <form name="checkListForm">
            <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
        </form>
        <div id="button">Add!</div>
        <br/>
        <div class="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(button).click(function(){
  var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
  $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');

 });
 $(document).on('click','.item', function(){
   $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

This code grabs a user's input, adds it to a list when you click a button, and removes the input from the list when you click on it within the div class item.

How can I make it so that I can return the value of "this"?

For example, if I add the word "test" to the list, and click on it to remove it.... how can grab the value of test from "this"?

Like.. document.write(this) returns [object HTMLDivElement].

I want document.write to return "test" if I click on it in the div.

I can't do document.write(toAdd) because toAdd doesn't exist in the second jquery ("on") function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
        $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');

    });
    $(document).on('click', '.item', function () {
        alert( $(this).text() ); // You can have `.html()` here too.
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Fiddle link [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/96LLB/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.innerHTML`:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(button).click(function(){
  var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
  $('.list').append('<div class="item">' + toAdd + '</div>');

 });
 $(document).on('click','.item', function(){
   document.write(this.innerHTML);
   $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: @Kamui `.innerHTML` is independent of jQuery, just for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the text inside the clicked item by `$(this).text()` . So you can do something like `document.write($(this).text())` before you remove the item.

Comment: Do remember the difference between .innerHTML and .text()
.innerHTML returns all html inside it, however .text() strips all tags and returns just the text.